# Energy transfer and electromagntism

Tags: electromagnetism, solid-state-physics, atomic-physics, material-science

How is  kinetic energy from one moving macroscopic object to a stationary object is transferred at a particle level?
Is all energy transfer that exists an effect of electromagntism at the particle level?

Comment: Yes, a collective effect of individual elementary interactions,